# Finding a file of specific length in directory (linux)

Tags: linux

I have twenty directories and im looking for a file with a known length somewhere in one of the directories.

Is there a Linux command to search a directory for a file by size?

What is the best method to locate this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard command to find files is **find**:-

```
find {directory} -size {byte count}c
```

If the directories are in disparate places, you can either use a **for** command to search each of the directories in turn, or create a specific directory with links (preferably hard links) to each of the directories, then find within that master directory.

Comment: (My answer crossed with choroba's, but I am leaving it in because of the extra information I gave about multiple directories.)

Comment: This was perfect. I love you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and its `-size` option:

```
find -size NNNc
```

`c` means the size in bytes.